# Optocoupler to drive LEDs (maybe with transistor)

Tags: phototransistor, optoelectronics

I wonder if there is some simple solution to drive LEDs powered from single rectified voltage.

[image: Schematic]

Assume AC is 220 V, each LEDs is 3.0 - 3.2 V 150 mA. I reckon series connection made it simpler but not sure if the optocoupler is able to provide the current.

Adding a BJT/MOSFET at the opto output should be OK but I am not sure how to connect it. Protective part can be advised but I wish to have the basic ON/OFF function working first.

EDIT on 2019-01-28 12:34

Actually, my design consists of two 30xLEDs paths and wish to end them with an optocoupler to Neutral.

Thanks to JonRB and Transistor, they discovered several fatal issues, so i retry and hope this would make more sense.

Refer to this [active current limiter](https://www.instructables.com/id/Power-LED-s---simplest-light-with-constant-current/), i wonder if the optocoupler can attach to it.
[image]
Now, with 60 x LEDs (3.0 - 3.2 V 150 mA):

```
100k Resistor to turn IRF740 FET On.
8 Ohm Resistor with BC817 BJT to limit the current to ~150mA.
Optocoupler PC817 would shutdown both transistors.
```

I think IRF740((400Vds) should be capable of AC peak voltage and current limiter can save the LEDs from destory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, check the datasheet:

https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/LED/PC817.pdf

The datasheet has two key pieces of information pertinent to your use-case

1. Collector current - 50mA
2. Collector-Emitter voltage - 35V

Your use case is targeting 150mA and thus this part is not suitable. Likewise you are stating this is powered from 220V (thus a peak of ~310V) yet this part has a Vce of 35V

Basically this part is not suitable for direct blocking.

A suitably rated FET would be. However... It isn't that simple. I have included an example circuit WITHOUT values as working with main potential isn't something you should do, unless you know what you are doing

The FET needs to have a blocking potential greater than the maximum DCLink voltage. It must be able to sink your target LED current.

The Zener is acting as a crude voltage regulator to limit the voltage applied to the gate. The resistive chain is dropping the vast majority of the DCLink potential.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRv4ZF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I understand PC817 won't work. I'd first remove the optocoupler label. I also try to avoid another track from the main. maybe I should add this to my question as well. btw, do you think it is impossible? although PS2533 is not popular, do you think it could do the job?

Comment: Please note that your circuit will destroy the LEDs - you have not included a current-limiting component. While I understand that you were focussing on the LED switching, the OP clearly does not understand the implications of your simplification.

Comment: As it stands yes (unless you say you  had 200odd in series and the RDS on is sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

The PC817 datasheet lists the **Absolute Maximum Ratings** as

```
Collector-emitter voltage    80 V
Emitter-collector voltage     6 V
Collector current            50 mA
Collector power dissipation 150 mW
```

With a 220 V AC supply and a diode rectifier you will have \$ 200 \sqrt 2 = 350 \ \text {V DC}\$ on the opto-terminals. It will die instantly.

Meanwhile, you have 30 LEDs in series with a minimum forward voltage drop of 3 V giving 90 V across the LEDs. Therefore the worst case voltage drop across the two 120 Ω parallel resistors is 350 - 90 = 260 V. The resistors will limit the current to \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {260}{60} = 4.3 \ \text A \$. The LEDs will be spectacularly brightly for a very short while.

Note that the power dissipated in each resistor is given by \$ P = I^2R = 2.15 \times 120 = 555 \ \text W \$.

Back to the drawing board, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok. thanks. seem I have to vanish this idea....maybe try a relay at rectifier input instead.

Comment: @Simon Your idea isn't impossible. You've just not considered the parts to use properly; you need to think about ratings when selecting parts.

Comment: @Simon - You seem to have concluded that you only need to use a relay rather than an optoisolator. This is not true. Please pay attention to the calculations involving LED current and resistor power. If you use a relay or a MOSFET (perJonRBs answer) you will destroy your LEDS. If, somehow, you don't, you will instead destroy your 180 ohm resistors.

Comment: ok, I should not give up so easily since I started up this question. please check if this current limiter works?

Comment: Have you calculated the power dissipation in your current limiter yet? (I haven't but I suspect that it's going to be very high.)

Comment: ok, maybe (1.41 x 220V - 60 x 3V ) x 150mA = 20W. so sad...

Comment: do you think it might work if i add a 100V zener diode after the rectifier diode and before the capacitor?

Comment: Again, what power will be dissipated in the Zener? You really need to do the calculations. You could also have a look at some capacitive voltage dropping circuits which don't suffer the high heat problems.